# Vosk Bug in Speech to Text script

Tags: python, multithreading, audio, while-loop, vosk

I am working on a python script that uses Vosk to transcripe OS and Mic audio. I want it to work with multiple threads.
Operational order:

1. start both audio streams
2. go into a while loop that reads from the streams and safes the data seperately
3. start a seperate thread that gets the audio-data as arguments and works with them to make it compatible with vosk.recognizer.AcceptWaveform() and .Result()

I got most of the code but am running into a really annoying bug with vosk that might just ruin my work of the last 3-4 days and where i need help.

I get this Error code:

```
WARNING (VoskAPI:BestPathEnd():lattice-incremental-online-decoder.cc:99) No final token found.
ASSERTION_FAILED (VoskAPI:TraceBackBestPath():lattice-incremental-online- decoder.cc:110) Assertion failed: (!iter.Done() && oarc != NULL)
WARNING (VoskAPI:BestPathEnd():lattice-incremental-online-decoder.cc:99) No final token found.
ASSERTION_FAILED (VoskAPI:TraceBackBestPath():lattice-incremental-online decoder.cc:110) Assertion failed: (!iter.Done() && oarc != NULL)
```

I get this a few times till the sript crashes.
I found this [link](https://github.com/alphacep/vosk-api/issues/998) that migth descripe my problem a bit better

Thx for your help

Comment: In the end my Question could also mean how to best queue threads without killing my localhost vosk server and cacheing all the data that is being collected in the while loop while the thread works with the data collected till then